# What are advanteges and disadvantages of the Visitor behavior pattern?

Tags: visitor-pattern

I'm doing a presentation about the visitor design pattern, I understand how it works and all, but I've yet to find "defined" advantages and disadvantages, and I don't wanna speculate the advantages or disadvantages myself, since I could set false information.

Comment: You could add your ideas of the advantages and disadvantages as a start for the discussion, so that it doesn't feel like we're doing your homework...

Comment: I don't pretend for you guys to do my homework lol, it's just that the teacher gave each of us a pattern to explain in class, and as I'm the one who is gonna explain it, and make a little hand out with the basic premise of how it works and all, I'd like to have the most accurate facts, so that my class doesn't go misinformed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some of my thoughts on the [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern:

Advantages:

- Main advantage: adding an action to all your Elements is really easy as you only have to implement the Visitor interface. No need to modify every Element object to add an action.
- You regroup actions common to many Elements in one single Visitor class. Only the code for that action is in that Visitor class. Makes the code easier to read if you want to know the code for one action specifically.

Disadvantages:

- Your Visitor can modify your Elements since an instance of the Element is sent to the Visitor. This is not recommended as it leads to [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). This can be fixed by making your object immutable.
- The code of the Element objects are spread out in all the Visitor objects. Therefore, the Element's logic lives in many classes. It makes the code harder to read if you want to look at the code for one Element object.
- It necessitates one new Visitor class for every action.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what @GammaOmega wrote, another drawback of the visitor pattern is that it is *invasive* because, to support the visitor pattern, the classes used in the tree structure must provide an `accept()` operation. If you need to work with an third-party tree structure that doesn't provide `accept()` operations, then you can't use the visitor pattern.

The pseudocode below shows how you can do a visitor-like tree traversal without polluting tree node classes with an `accept()` operation.

```
void walk(TreeNode * node, NodeProcessor * processorObj)
{
  //--------
  // This switch statement is used instead of accept() operations
  // on nodes in a tree.
  //--------
  switch (node->getNodeType()) {
  case NT_module:
    processorObj->processModule((TreeModuleNode*)node);
    break;
  case NT_interface:
    processorObj->processInterface((TreeInterfaceNode*)node);
    break;
  ... // other cases omitted for brevity
  }

  //--------
  // Recurse down the tree
  //--------
  if (node->isScope()) {
    TreeScopeNode * scope = (TreeScopeNode*)(node);
    foreach child in scope->getChildren() {
      walk(child, processorObj);
    }
  }
}
```